# I am not able to kill a child process using TerminateProcess

Tags: c++, createprocess

I have a problem to kill a child process using `TerminateProcess`. I call to this function and the process still there (in the Task Manager). This piece of code is called many times launching the same program.exe many times and these process are there in the task manager which i think is not good.
Actually is created two process all the time: the program.exe and conhost.exe.

I will really appreciate any help.

Here is the code:

```
STARTUPINFO childProcStartupInfo;
memset( &childProcStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(childProcStartupInfo));
childProcStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(childProcStartupInfo);
childProcStartupInfo.hStdInput = hFromParent;   // stdin
childProcStartupInfo.hStdOutput = hToParent;    //  stdout
childProcStartupInfo.hStdError = hToParentDup;  // stderr
childProcStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
childProcStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;


PROCESS_INFORMATION childProcInfo;  /* for CreateProcess call */



bOk = CreateProcess(
    NULL,           // filename
    pCmdLine,   // full command line for child
    NULL,           // process security descriptor */
    NULL,           // thread security descriptor */
    TRUE,           // inherit handles? Also use if STARTF_USESTDHANDLES */
    0,              // creation flags */
    NULL,           // inherited environment address */
    NULL,           // startup dir; NULL = start in current */
    &childProcStartupInfo,          // pointer to startup info (input) */
    &childProcInfo);            // pointer to process info (output) */

CloseHandle( hFromParent );
CloseHandle( hToParent );
CloseHandle( hToParentDup );

CloseHandle( childProcInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle( childProcInfo.hProcess);

TerminateProcess( childProcInfo.hProcess ,0);  //this is not working, the process
```

Comment: The process handle has already been closed via `CloseHandle`, so `TerminateProcess` will never succeed.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks that is good point, I removed and i think is working. but i have another problem, where to put this terminateprocess function because the process should terminate when this process finish.

Answer (score 6):

There are two possible reasons that I know of:

- you can't kill a process running under a different security context than the one of the process which calls TerminateProcess ([see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155075))
- the process is [doing something in kernel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) mode (e.g. some unfinished I/O operations by driver, etc) - I believe this was introduced with Vista, but I might be wrong

Comment: The second was what I had in mind. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx

Comment: Hi Zdelav, thanks for your quick response, actually i did not get any message error when the TerminateProcess is executed (the link shared is talking about that). And I am using Windows Vista.

Comment: which of the links? the error 'Access is denied' is shown by task manager. `TerminateProcess` returns BOOL and you can call `GetLastError` to check the reason. If you store the return of `GetLastError` into some variable `err` and add a watch in debugger like `err,hr` you will also see the description or the error.

Comment: The response from TerminateProcess is 0, and the message is "the handle is invalid" what means that?

Comment: It means that you have just closed that handle, so it's invalid.