# How to terminate the process created by the child process created by childProcess.exec?

Tags: node.js

### Problem

As you can see from the code below, I'm executing a command on `ffmpeg.exe` bin using `childProcess.exec()` which creates 2 OS processes:

- The child process: `cmd.exe`
- The child's child process `ffmpeg.exe`

I'd like to be able to cancel the operation by terminating the `ffmpeg.exe` process, but neither of the following methods work, since `ffmpeg.exe` is a separate process:

- Method 1: `const terminatingProcess = childProcess.exec('kill ' + process.pid)`
- Method 2: `videoConversionProcess.kill()`

I cannot simply terminate the returned `pid` with another process or run `.kill()` on the `videoConversionProcess` since it terminates the `cmd.exe` process, not the `ffmpeg.exe` process which it spawned.

### Code

```js
const command = '"E:\\test\\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "VIDEO_URL" -vcodec copy -c copy "E:\\test\\video.ts"'
const videoConversionProcess= childProcess.exec(command)

videoConversionProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data)     
})
```

When I log the `videoConversionProcess` I can see the information about the `cmd.exe` that it spawned, but not the `ffmpeg.exe` which is doing all the work:

```
ChildProcess {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _closesNeeded: 3, _closesGot: 0, …}
connected: false
exitCode: null
killed: true
pid: 18804
signalCode: "SIGTERM"
spawnargs: Array(5)
0: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
1: "/d"
2: "/s"
3: "/c"
4: ""E:\test\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "VIDEO_URL" -vcodec copy -c copy "E:\test\video.ts"
...
```

### Question

How do I terminate the operation?

Is there a way to exec the command on the `ffmpeg.exe` and make Node.js aware of this process? I tried using `spawn` instead of `exec` but I couldn't make it work, it didn't spawn the `ffmpeg.exe` process at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't kill child process on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705857/cant-kill-child-process-on-windows). It suggests using Windows `taskkill` instead of `kill`, allowing you to include the child processes

Comment: @thatotherguy hmm, I'm not sure it's the same thing because I'm already executing the command directly on the `ffmpeg.exe`. Let me try those solutions

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the [top voted, awarded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814686/1899640)'s suggestion for using `taskkill`. The suggestions for running the script directly do not apply, including the accepted answer.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks, one of those solutions worked for me. I was searching for the solution for like 2 hours, and for some reason google didn't lead me to that thread, thank you for letting me know about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, you can try to follow [this](https://medium.com/@almenon214/killing-processes-with-node-772ffdd19aad) guide.

In brief, to kill a process in windows you could do:

```
    exec(`taskkill /PID ${pid} /T /F`, (error, stdout, stderr)=>{
        console.log("taskkill stdout: " + stdout)
        console.log("taskkill stderr: " + stderr)
        if(error){
            console.log("error: " + error.message)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, it terminated both processes